# Python - best way to wait until a remote system is booted

Tags: python, python-requests, wait

I am using wake on lan to start a certain server in a python script.

The server is online when I can do a successfull API request, such as:

```
return requests.get(
        url + path,
        auth=('user', user_password),
        headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        verify=False,
        timeout=0.05
    ).json()
```

What is the best method to wait for the server bootup process (until it is reachable via API) without spamming the network with requests in a loop?

Comment: network requests are cheap, do like per second.

Comment: HEAD requests are cheap. No need for a full GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're very close. Why not put that request in `while` a d `try except` blocks?

```py
while True:
    try:
        return requests.head(...)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: On line 4 it should be `requests`

Answer (score 0):

Your two choices are to poll the remote service until it responds or configure the service to in some way notify you that it's up.

There's really nothing wrong with sending requests in a loop, as long as you don't do so unnecessarily often. If the service takes ~10 seconds to come up, checking once a second would be reasonable. If it takes ~10 minutes, every 30 seconds or so would probably be fine.

The alternative - some sort of push notification - is more elegant, but it requires you having some other service up and running already, listening for the notification. For example you could start a simple webserver locally before restarting the remote service and have the remote service make a request against your server when it's ready to start handling requests.

Generally speaking I would start with the polling approach since it's easier and involves fewer moving parts. Just be sure you design your polling in a fault-tolerant way; in particular be sure to specify a maximum time to wait or number of polling attempts to make before giving up. Otherwise your script will just hang if the remote service never comes up.